# How to forward arguments to `npm run start` when running a docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker

Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as a parent image
FROM node:18

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY lib/ ./lib
COPY sql/ ./sql
COPY tsconfig.json ./

RUN npm run build

# Specify the command to run your app with custom arguments
ENTRYPOINT npm run start
```

Usual command I use in nodejs to start my app (when not using docker) :

```
npm run start -- --host "127.0.0.1" --port 3306 --user "root"
```

After running `docker build -t demo:latest .`

I have tried every possible combination of arguments without success.

`docker run demo -- -- host "127.0.0.1" --port 3306 --user "root"` <= does not forward correctly the arguments

How to correctly forward them?

Comment: Can't you just tack those on to the start script in package.json instead?

Comment: @Phix I want to let the user of the image decide what configuration to use

Comment: You'll need to use the "exec" form of the ENTRYPOINT command: `ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start"]`

Comment: For what it's worth, I typically use environment variables instead.  In JavaScript: `process.env.PORT` and then `docker run -e PORT=3306`

Comment: For the specific things you show, `--host` should _always_ be 0.0.0.0 in a container; any fixed `--port` will work, since multiple containers can have the same ports and you can remap them on the host; and the effective user can also be specified as a `docker run -u` option.  You may not need additional arguments here.

Comment: @DavidMaze my docker app should connect to a db outside from this container, can you confirm your sentence applies to this case?

Comment: Those settings only matter for connections into the container, and they won't be different if the database is in another container, outside the container on the same host, or on a remote system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ENTRYPOINT npm run start` to `ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start"]`

## Explanation

The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) for `ENTRYPOINT` says that there are two forms of the directive:

#### The ***exec*** form, which is the preferred form:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]
```

Which **does** pass command line args from `docker run`.

#### The ***shell*** form:

```
ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2
```

Which does **not** pass command line args from `docker run`.

---

Relevant bits, quoted directly from the documentation:

##### Exec form

> Command line arguments to `docker run <image>` will be appended after all elements in an *exec* form `ENTRYPOINT`, and will override all elements specified using `CMD`. This allows arguments to be passed to the entry point, i.e., `docker run <image> -d` will pass the `-d` argument to the entry point.

##### Shell form

> This form will use shell processing to substitute shell environment variables, and will **ignore** any `CMD` or `docker run` command line arguments.

Answer (score -1):

Change
`ENTRYPOINT npm run start`
to
`ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "start"]`